# Javascript Element.style CSSStyleDeclaration object's properties look wierd?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have a button in a HTML file,

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Use JavaScript to change the color of that button to red.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
btn.style['background-color'] = 'red';
```

Then I checked the `btn.style['background-color']`. It showed `red`.

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(`This button is in ${btn.style['background-color']}`)
});
```

So I expected that my `btn.style` object should look like this,

```
{
  ... ,
  "background-color": "red",
  ... 
}
```

But when I print them in the console, **why the key-value pair is `0: "background-color"`, and where is value `red`?**

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', () => console.dir(btn.style));
```

[image]

Comment: [CSSStyleDeclaration is not a regular object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration). Do not be worried about the console log output. If you use `btn.style['background-color']` it will return `'red'`

Comment: @evolutionxbox So what it actually is?

Comment: It's an object (take a look at the link I gave). It's just the console output that looks odd. Firefox logs it as you expect.

Comment: Javascript likes CamelCase, but CSS likes SnakeCase, I know I wish CSS used CamelCase too  :(

Comment: @Keith see, I prefer dashes to camelcase. It find it a lot easier to read.

Comment: @evolutionxbox interface? I need some time to digest it... thx for the reference!

Comment: Seems they hate SnakeCase so much. I smell the contempt from the screen.

Comment: @shen it's not hate, just a different outlook on naming. It's not worse or bad, just different.

Comment: @evolutionxbox u r right, not hate, just try to adapt to both two different convention.

Comment: In order to make it faster to read values set, they put in dummy values with integer strings in order starting from zero. To read, you just have to loop through the integers as strings and once you find a number missing, you can stop. Each of those dummy entries are ones which have values set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) object is a bit exotic. If you look at `btn.style["background-color"]` or `btn.style.backgroundColor` directly, you'll see `red` (or some representation of red, it varies by browser).

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
btn.style['background-color'] = 'red';

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(btn.style["background-color"]);
    console.log(btn.style.backgroundColor);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

In the console output you showed, you'll find it under `backgroundColor`:

[image: console output showing backgroundColor: red with a circle around it]

Comment: but how does `btn.style['background-color']` link to `backgroundColor` property?

Comment: @shen - Code in the `CSSStyleDeclaration` object implementation in the browser does it, so you can use either CSS convention or JavaScript convention. (You could do the same sort of thing in your own code if you needed to via a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object.)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the Specification for the CSSStyleDeclaration, you get a bit more of the inner workings of the handling of CSS in JavaScript.

These are the steps that JS takes to save your CSS styles:

1. If you supply a camelCase version of a property name, the [CSS property to IDL attribute algorithm](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#css-property-to-idl-attribute) converts the string into dash-case, so it can be used later
2. The [`setProperty(property, value, priority)`](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-setproperty) method is called, property being the dash-case version of the property name (e.g. `background-color`), and value being the value the property should be set to without `!important` flags (e.g. `"red"`)
3. The property gets pushed into an internal NodeList structure, the [CSSDeclaration](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#css-declaration), which holds the property name, value, important flag and a case-sensitive flag
4. Now, the style is computed, this is up to the implementation of the browser mostly, there is certain restrictions on property order and mapping logic ([here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-logical-1/#mapping-logic)) and of course there are other specifications for how elements should behave

Now, to access these properties, internally, there is both an array of all computed properties as well as the aforementioned NodeList to get values by their property name. The methods to access these are [`item(index)`](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-item).

Which is why, when you look at your CSSStyleDeclaration on the console there is a `0: "background-color"` at the top, it's the first (computed) property in the NodeList for the element, so `e.style.item(0)` will return `"background-color"`.

If you now want to get the value of the property, you can use [`getPropertyValue(property)`](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-getpropertyvalue) which goes through the NodeList and finds the item with the corresponding property name and returns it's value.

JavaScript has short-hands for these function, through the Object index ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/item)), so `e.style[property]` runs the `getPropertyValue()` for that property name, and through an Array index for the `item(index)` method, so `e.style[index]` runs the `item()` method.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
btn.style['background-color'] = 'red';

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(btn.style[0], btn.style.item(0));
    console.log(btn.style[btn.style[0]], btn.style.getPropertyValue(btn.style.item(0)));
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Crystal clear! I should have also accept this answer:) Great explanation.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could be of help!